# Convert Word docx to Excel using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, openxml

Is there any way to convert Word document where I have some tables into Excel file?
It would be very helpful to convert tables.

Something like that:

- Open Word document using OpenXML
- Find all tables xml-tags
- Copy xml-tags
- Create Excel file
- Insert xml-tags with table from Word to new Excel file

I mean

```
void OpenWordDoc(string filePath)
{
_documentWord = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true);
}

List<string> GetAllTablesXMLTags()
{
//find and copy
}

List<string> CreateExcelFile(string filePath)
{
TemplateExcelDocument excelDocument = new TemplateExcelDocument();
_documentExcel = excelDocument.CreatePackage(filePath);
}

void InsertXmlTagsToExcelFile(string filePath)
{
CreateExcelFiles(filePath);
var xmlTable = GetAllTablesXMLTags();
// ... insert to _documentExcel
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your steps are correct.

I would like to share some sdk documents, hope it could help to some extent:

[Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854)

When handling the word tables:

[Working with WordprocessingML tables (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278313.aspx)

When processing excel tables:

[Working with the shared string table (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278314.aspx)

[Working with SpreadsheetML tables (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278320.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

to get all tables in the docx file you can use code below :

```
using System;
using Independentsoft.Office;
using Independentsoft.Office.Word;
using Independentsoft.Office.Word.Tables;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WordDocument doc = new WordDocument("c:\\test.docx");

            Table[] tables = doc.GetTables();

            foreach (Table table in tables)
            {
                //read data
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And to write them into an excel file you have to do this for each cell :

```
 app.Visible = false;
        workbooks = app.Workbooks;
        workbook =  workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
        worksheet = (_Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
        excel(row, column, "value");
        workbook.Saved = true;
        workbook.SaveAs(output_file);
        app.UserControl = false;
        app.Quit();
```

and finally excel function is as below :

```
    public void excel(int row, int column, string value)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, column] = value;
    }
```

Also you can use `CSV` or `HTML` format to create an excel file. to do that simply create a file `example.xlsx` with this content for CSV comma delmiated :

> col1,col2,col3,col4 \n
>
> val1,val2,val3val4 \n

or in HTML format :

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>col1</td>
  <td>col2</td>
  <td>col3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>val1</td>
  <td>val2</td>
  <td>val3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need similar function but using OpenXML